# Is there any difference in Kendo UI Gantt Chart for mvc and jquery

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using Kendo UI controls in our project. I just want to know is there any difference in kendo ui controls for ASP Net MVC and Kendo UI for jquery? Which one I should use in my mvc 5 project?

Comment: The MVC helpers generate the jquery statements for you. I suggest using them.

Comment: A similar question was made here concerning not Gantt chart in particular but all components. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308815/difference-between-kendo-ui-web-and-kendo-ui-asp-net-for-mvc